# How to print all the facts?

Tags: list, printing, prolog, fact

I am stuck for this problem...

```
isAt(keys, room3).
isAt(book, room3).
isAt(keys, room6).
isAt(keys, room4).
```

currently, room3 have keys and book.
I want to print keys and book.
I tried this code and apparently prints only one. (just keys)

```
look :- isIn(Location),
  write('You are in '),
  write(Location),
  nl,
  items_inroom(Location),
  nl.


items_inroom(Location) :-
    isIn(Location),
    isAt(Item, Location),
    write('Available Item(s):'), 
    write(Item),
    nl.

items_inroom(_) :-
    write('Available Item(s): None'),
    nl.
```

items_inroom is the code that trying to print all these facts.
How can I approach this?
any help will be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all items and display them.

```
items_inroom(Location) :-
    write('Available Item(s):'),
    findall(Item, isAt(Item, Location), Items),
    show_items(Items).

show_items([]) :-
    write('None'), !.

show_items(Items) :- 
    write(Items).
```

Actually you can implement the `show_items(Items)` in any way you want.

Comment: Ideally, you would want to use `bagof/3` or `setof/3` instead of `findall` (since they fail if there are no solutions, and don't trample over choice points the way that `findall` does).

Comment: @Boris You are right. My main intention was to clearly separate *data handling* and *user interface*.

Answer (score 2):

From Chapter 11 in ["The Craft of Prolog"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/craft-prolog) by Richard O'Keefe, a bit simplified/refactored to save keystrokes:

```
print_item_report(Location) :-
    (   setof(Item, isAt(Item, Location), Items)
    ->  format("Items available in ~w:~n", [Location]),
        forall(member(I, Items),
               format("~w~n", [I]))
        % print_item_report_footer
    ;   format("No items in ~w~n", [Location])
    ).

% etc
```

If you don't have `format` for whatever reason, you can still use `write`. If you don't have `forall`, then this:

```
forall(Condition, Action)
```

is defined as

```
\+ (Condition, \+ Action )
```

so you can use that instead. See [the SWI-Prolog `forall/2` documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=forall2) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`items_inroom/1` predicate will always print the first occurrence of `Item` on all facts `isAt/2`. You need to loop over all the facts `isAt/2`, use a metapredicate [`setof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof/3), [`bagog/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3) or [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3), I will recomend `setof/3` like @Boris did, or build your own bucle (maybe not the best idea, but it's an option):

```
show_items(Location):- isAt(Item, Location),   % Condition
                     write(Item), nl,          % Process result
                     fail.                     % force backtracking to evaluate condition and find a new result
show_items(_).                                 % return true when all options have been evaluated
```